# numpaddiv isn't sending in script

Tags: keyboard, numpad

I made a script so that when I type `{numpaddiv}`, it'll send `{numpaddiv} + ⪨`
unfortunately `numpaddiv` isn't sending

```
numpaddiv::
    send, {numpaddiv}
    send, ⪨
return
```

it only sends the "⪨" symbol.

I've tried as many things as I can think of.